# How can I configure event registrations to enable a user to register a third party but get an invoice in their name?

Tags: civievent, invoice

From what I can understand, when registering for an event in Civi using the built-in registration form, and with invoicing turned on, the system assumes that a logged in user is registering themselves (and perhaps others in addition). The form provides a 'Not You' link to enable a user to register a third party, but in that scenario the invoice will also be made out in the name of the third party and sent to them.

What I'd like to do is provide the option for a user to register, for example, one of their colleagues, but that the invoice is made out in their name and sent to them rather than the registered participant. The registered participant just receives a notification that they have been registered for the event.

Has anyone got a solution that works for this? I guess I can build a Drupal webform to handle it, but it feels like something that Civi should be able to handle.

Comment: Just to add to this, where multiple participants are registered it appears to use the name of the first participant on the invoice, but sends a copy of the invoice to all participants. But not to the person paying, if they are logged in (and therefore known to Civi) but not registering themselves.